# How can I easily get the length of a piece of text?

Tags: cursor-motions, visual-mode, counting

I sometimes want to check the length of a piece of text, for example in this
example:

```
str = 'Hello, world!'
if len(str) == 13:
    print('Hello back to you!')
```

I would like to know the length of the string `Hello, world!`.

What I do now, is have the column number in `rulerformat` with `%c`, I put my
cursor on the first character, then go to the last, and manually substract.

This is rather awkward, though. What I want is, for example, the length of my
selection in virtual mode in the ruler, but there is no option for this as far
as I can see.

Can this be done? Or in some other easier way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set the `showcmd` option. From Vim's help:

```
Show (partial) command in the last line of the screen.  Set this
option off if your terminal is slow.
In Visual mode the size of the selected area is shown:
- When selecting characters within a line, the number of characters.
  If the number of bytes is different it is also displayed: "2-6"
  means two characters and six bytes.
- When selecting more than one line, the number of lines.
- When selecting a block, the size in screen characters:
  {lines}x{columns}.
```

It should be on by default on Vim if you have `nocompatible` set.

Then, simply select what you want, and Vim will display the number of characters, or lines selected on the bottom right.

Comment: Well, that was certainly simpler than I would have expected :-)